# how to test for a specific watermark in an image with python2.7

Tags: python, image, image-processing, watermark

there is this project am currently working on, which requires me to watermark every uploaded image. i have tried series of examples online, but they  are not giving me what i really want as result

**for example**

i have an image A with image B watermarked on it, the two images are of the same dimensions. i applied opacity of 0.5 on image B before placing it on image A

now, i would really appreciate if anyone could help with a boolean function to check if image A has already been watermarked with image B before watermarking it.

**thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on several factors that you'll need to provide more information for.

For instance, how complex are these images? Is there a lot of noise? Are the images that are uploaded similar in any way, or are they heterogenous? Are the watermarks always the same, or are they different?

As a general principle for extracting objects from images, you should look into processes such as color deconvolution, thresholding, and blob extraction.

In short--some sample images would go a long way...

Comment: Yeah,talking about the types of images uploaded, I don't think there is any way I would be able to detect if they are similar of heterogeneous as the images depends solemnly on where, when , and how they are been taken by users. And also, yes, the watermarks are always the same, and always at a specific position on every image. would have attached some images to the question, but I couldn't due to stackoverflow requirement .

Answer (score -1):

yeah,  finally found a dubious way to solve the problem, by hiding a specific text on the alpha layer of the image after watermarking it using **steganography**.

so on every upload, i get the image, iterate through the lowest pixels of the image's alpha layer, then compare the result to the text. if the result matches the text, definitely, the image has been watermarked.